# Can I include the restTemplate request body inside restTemplate.setErrorHandler?

Tags: java, spring-boot

Here In the below simple code of RestTemplate's errorHandler I want to include the request body inside the log

I want to keep the code clean and not using the error handler out side restTemplate configuration class. So the only way i found is to handel it from rest template caller/user, WDYT?

```
@Configuration
public class HTTPConfiguration {
...

 restTemplate.setErrorHandler(new DefaultResponseErrorHandler() {

            @Override
            public void handleError(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException {

                if (response.getStatusCode().series() == HttpStatus.Series.SERVER_ERROR) {

                    LOGGER.error("Server error: {} {}", response.getStatusCode(), response.getStatusText());

                } else if (response.getStatusCode().series() == HttpStatus.Series.CLIENT_ERROR) {

                    LOGGER.error("Client error: {} {}", response.getStatusCode(), response.getStatusText());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public boolean hasError(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException {

                return (response.getStatusCode().series() == HttpStatus.Series.CLIENT_ERROR
                        || response.getStatusCode().series() == HttpStatus.Series.SERVER_ERROR);
            }
});


...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The straight answer is no, `ResponseErrorHandler` is an interface and only has three methods, the best you can get is request url and request method [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/ResponseErrorHandler.html)

> handleError(ClientHttpResponse response)

```
Handle the error in the given response.
```

> handleError(java.net.URI url, HttpMethod method, ClientHttpResponse response)

```
Alternative to handleError(ClientHttpResponse) with extra information providing access to the request URL and HTTP method.
```

> handleError(java.net.URI url, HttpMethod method, ClientHttpResponse response)

```
Indicate whether the given response has any errors.
```

And `ResponseErrorHandler` has two implementation classes `DefaultResponseErrorHandler, ExtractingResponseErrorHandler` but none of them has method with `HttpEntity` as an argument [DefaultResponseErrorHandler](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/DefaultResponseErrorHandler.html),and [ExtractingResponseErrorHandler](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/ExtractingResponseErrorHandler.html)